# how to update cart without refresh page in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, ajax, ubercart

I am using [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) module for products in Drupal 7. When I click on 'add to cart' button my cart is not updating. After page refresh cart showing product means update. I am using this code :

```
<?php
$number_of_items = count(uc_cart_get_contents());
if ($number_of_items == 0) { ?>
  <a href="/cart">Your cart is empty.</a>
<? } else if ($number_of_items == 1) { ?>
  <a href="/cart" class="itemincart"><? echo $number_of_items; ?> item in cart.</a>
<? } else {?>
  <a href="/cart" class="itemincart"><? echo $number_of_items; ?> items in cart.</a>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Use "Ubercart AJAX Cart" Module
https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_ajax_cart

Comment: Can I do this without module.